# How to set implicit Object Response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I would like to move the following code in Javascript:

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition:", "attachment; filename="+file); 
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Please suggest how to acheive this.

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the response headers for a file download via Javascript. Your server will have to do that (or the browser needs to be able to figure it out by itself, for example from the file name in the URL).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set HTTP headers. You can't do that with Javascript.

The HTTP headers are received and interpreted by the users browser before it interprets the HTML, which is done before interpreting any embedded Javascript, which is done before executing any Javascript. The moment where you can do anything with Javascript is already too late to edit any HTTP headers.

What problem do you want to solve? Maybe we can come up with a different solution.